# Yii2 gridview filter from a list of multiple value (not dropdown list filter)

Tags: gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app

My gridview data

```
    day          modeler    total  
    2018-1-05     ABC        5                         
    2018-1-06     DEF        8        
    2018-1-06     CAB        3   
    2018-1-06     GHI        3   
    2018-1-06     KLM        3
```

I have a gridview like this. Right now and can only filter modeler one by one. Can I have a multiple line searchbox and just paste in "ABC DEF CAB" and it will filter 3 results like below?

```
day          modeler    total  
2018-1-05     ABC        5                         
2018-1-06     DEF        8        
2018-1-06     CAB        3
```

My controller

```
public function actionIndex()
{
    $searchModel = new ModelerSearch();
    $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

    return $this->render('index', [
        'searchModel' => $searchModel,
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ]);
}
```

My search model

```
   public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Modeler::find();

        // add conditions that should always apply here

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        // grid filtering conditions
        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'modeler', $this->modeler])
            ->andFilterWhere(['like', 'total', $this->total]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: cant understand what you mean by "currently i filter models one by one" ?

Comment: i can i can just filter "ABC" or "DEF" only

Comment: so what i understand is that you want a single text field where if you enter  `"ABC"`  it should show you matching record and if you enter  `"ABC DEF"` with space it should show you 2 records matching either one of them ? if it is correct you need to add the code related to your `searchmodel` , `view` and controller `action`

Comment: Sorry for the late update. I used Gii to generate CRUD. I think i don't need to add the code :)

Comment: i know but for suggesting update i wont be writing all the code :) , so its better you add the related code and i will update it accordingly where every needed, this way you can just replace the code at your end and test if it is correct or not, so kindly add the controller action and the `search()` function from the `SearchModel`

Comment: I've updated the code :) thank you

Comment: added an answer see if it helps you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to search via the `modeler` field in the gridview and you want it to work in a way that if you enter `"ABC"` it should show you matching record and if you enter `"ABC DEF"` with space it should show you 2 records matching either one of them.

So, first of all, on top of your search Model add

```
private $_selections = [];
```

And then update your search function to the following

```
public function search( $params ) {
    $query = Modeler::find ();

    // add conditions that should always apply here

    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider ( [
        'query' => $query ,
            ] );

    $this->load ( $params );

    if ( !$this->validate () ) {
        // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
        // $query->where('0=1');
        return $dataProvider;
    }

    if ( $this->modeler !== null && $this->modeler !== '' ) {
        $this->_selections = preg_split ( '/\s+/i' , $this->modeler );
        $query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'IN' , 'modeler' , $this->_selections ] );
    }
    // grid filtering conditions
    $query->andFilterWhere ( [
        'id' => $this->id ,
    ] );

    $query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'like' , 'total' , $this->total ] );

    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Now go to your gridview and in the `modeler` column type in the filter input `"ABC DEF"` and watch it happen.

Comment: @SaoHo i updated the answer there was an extra check the second one it could be replaced  with the first check `if ( $this->modeler !== null && $this->modeler !== '' ) {` so we can move the line `$query->andFilterWhere ( [ 'IN' , 'modeler' , $this->_searchQuery ] );` inside it. see updated code.

Comment: yes i figured it out :) thank you, by the way, i tried filter about a thousand modeler, it returns error, the URL length exceeds the capacity limit. Do you know if I can fix it by increasing the limit?

Comment: are you getting error in console against  the ajax request

Comment: Apache server only support 4000 characters in URL. If I filter a lot of value it will return this errors. Can I use "POST" instead of "GET" method for search model? If not then it's okay :)

Comment: yes you can but you need to change the queryParams to post in controller action and change the options for pjax see this post http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/58087-yii2-gridview-filter-how-we-change-get-to-post/ @SaoHo